# Student absent for 5 consecutive days excluding Holidays

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, mariadb, gaps-and-islands

I am using code igniter and attendance table as below:

```
attendance ID   timestamp   student_id     status
     1           01-01-20        1           P
     2           01-01-20        2           P
     3           02-01-20        1           P
     4           02-01-20        2           A
     5           03-01-20        1           P
     6           03-01-20        2           A
     7           04-01-20        1           H
     8           04-01-20        2           H
     9           05-01-20        1           P
     10          05-01-20        2           A
```

My target is to get the student id who is absent for 3 consecutive days for the period of the last 1 month from today excluding the holidays in the middle like in the above table the student id 2 should be the one with 3 consecutive absence excluding the holiday on the 4th Jan.

I am using Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28 with mysql. I have been able to get the consecutive 3 absent but when there is a holiday in the middle, I fail to find a work around there. here is my existing code:

```
SELECT *,
CASE
   WHEN (@studentID  = student_id) THEN @absentRun := IF(status = A, 0, @absentRun + 1)
   WHEN (@studentID := student_id) THEN @absentRun := IF(status = A, @absentRun + 1, 0)
END AS absentRun
FROM attendance
Where timestamp BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE() AND year='2019-2020'
ORDER BY student_id, timestamp;
```

I would really really appreciate a quick answer from someone to help me with this. I am really hope to have a solution since I have posted here for help for the first time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Funny thing is that student 2 was present, absent and on holiday the same day, while, the same day, student 1 was present and on holiday. Are there quantum students ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this as a variant of the gaps and island problem. Here is one way to solve it using `row_number()` (available in MySQL 8.0) - the difference between the row numbers gives you the group each record belongs to.

```
select 
    student_id,
    min(timestamp) timestamp_start,
    max(timestramp) timestamp_end
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by student_id order by timestamp) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by student_id, status order by timestamp) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
where status = 2
group by student_id, rn1 - rn2
having count(*) >= 5
```

This will give you one record for each streak of at least 5 consecutive days of absence for each student. As a bonus, the query also displays the starting and ending date of each streak.

Comment: Since i am new to this. I accidentally posted it before it was final. and to my surpise I even got answers. I am impress. I have to be fast to keep up with this. :)

Comment: I tried that but getting the following error:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by student_id order by timestamp) rn1, row_number() over(part' at line 8


Line Number: 189

Comment: @user3734397: which version of MariaDB are you using? Window functions were added in Maria DB 10.2.0.

Comment: Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: @user3734397: without window functions, your question will be much harder to solve. You should consider switching to a newer version rather than sticking to 10.1.... Version 10.2.0 was released in April 2016 (which was actually before 10.1019, which you are using and was released in November 2016). And latest stable version is 10.4.11!

Comment: I guess it is not the version it is something with the query. I even tested the same on my online Server version: 5.6.41-84.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.1, Revision b308619

Comment: Still waiting for help.

Comment: @user3734397: it is not about the query, it is about the version of the database products that you are running. This query requires MariaDB 10.2.0 / MySQL 8.0.