# Consecutive Absent Students Excluding Holidays

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I want to have 124 ID student to be retrieved since I want 4 days consecutive absent student within the last 8 days ignoring the weekend H. 124 student had been absent for 3 consecutive days before the weekend and he was also absent after the weekend on Monday so he is the one to be retrieve since consecutively absent for 4 days

I tried this which works fine but this query **only works with MySQL 8.1** whereas **I'm using an older version 5.6.41-84.1** and PHP version: 7.4.33.

How can I do this on my version of MySQL?

| attendance_id | timestamp | student_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-05 | 124 | P |
| 2 | 2023-11-05 | 125 | P |
| 3 | 2023-11-06 | 124 | A |
| 4 | 2023-11-06 | 125 | P |
| 5 | 2023-11-07 | 124 | A |
| 6 | 2023-11-07 | 125 | P |
| 7 | 2023-11-08 | 124 | A |
| 8 | 2023-11-08 | 125 | P |
| 9 | 2023-11-09 | 124 | H |
| 10 | 2023-11-09 | 125 | H |
| 11 | 2023-11-10 | 124 | H |
| 12 | 2023-11-10 | 125 | H |
| 13 | 2023-11-11 | 124 | A |
| 14 | 2023-11-11 | 125 | P |
| 15 | 2023-11-12 | 124 | P |
| 16 | 2023-11-12 | 125 | P |

```php
$query = $this->db->query("
select *,
    student_id,
    min(timestamp) timestamp_start,
    max(timestamp) timestamp_end
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by student_id order by timestamp) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by student_id, status order by timestamp) rn2
    from attendance t
) t
where status = A AND timestamp BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
group by student_id, rn1 - rn2
having count(*) >= 4");
```

Comment: Please double-check your input data after my edit. Are you using PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: Why are you passing `4` as a string in `count(*) >= '4'`?

Comment: Sorry I did the correction 4 is integer. Thanks. I am using MySQLi.

Comment: What's your excuse for still running MySQL 5?

Comment: Yes sir. I am using MySQL 5.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question... I'm asking **why** are you on 5.x?

Comment: It looks like you are registering present or absent for every day when student could be present ie no weekends are included in the registration process?

Comment: You could fetch all the attendances from the last 8 days and do the processing in PHP. Just make sure to put an index on the `timestamp` column.

Comment: If I fetch all users attendance may slow it down a bit. I was wondering if I could retrieve only those students who fit the greater than 4 absent days.

Comment: How many students do you have? If you fetch only absent attendances in the last eight days, the retrieved data should be small.

Comment: Olivier, thanks a lot for your time to help me. I guess even getting all the students absent in the last 8 days is not much. Even if we go ahead with that, any idea what query you would suggest and how to iterate through the results. I do really appreciate your efforts to help.

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/252532/1741542, especially the link included to [Calculating Work Days](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/calculatingworkdays/1660/). This is about SQL Server, but maybe you can adapt it to MySQL.

Comment: Yes sir I did review that but I am unable to work out how to achieve the desired result in my case. which is why I posted here.

Comment: This is sometimes called a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem.

Comment: *"what query you would suggest"* Just `SELECT student_id, timestamp FROM attendance WHERE status = 2 AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY ORDER BY student_id, timestamp`

Comment: Outline of the solution: You will need two distinct subqueries, both of which emulate the ROW_NUMBER() function. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ Then join them. Emulating it is a huge pain in the xxse neck, that's why people suggest you upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [suggested that you should upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897238/student-absent-for-5-consecutive-days-excluding-holidays#comment105924245_59897374) the best part of four years ago. You really should stop putting it off.

This is a horrible solution but it works, I think. It creates a grouping similar to that in your ROW_NUMBER based query:

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    MIN(timestamp) AS ts_start,
    MAX(timestamp) AS ts_end
FROM (
    SELECT attendance.*,
        IF (@prev_student <> student_id, (@prev_student := student_id) AND (@grp := 0), null) AS reset,
        @grp := IF (status = 'P', @grp + 1, @grp) AS grp
    FROM attendance
    JOIN (SELECT @prev_student := 0, @grp := 0) AS init
    WHERE status IN ('A', 'P')
    AND timestamp BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 8 DAY
                      AND CURRENT_DATE
    ORDER BY student_id, timestamp
) a
WHERE status = 'A'
GROUP BY student_id, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4;
```

The derived table is:

| attendance_id | timestamp | student_id | status | reset | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-05 | 124 | P | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-11-06 | 124 | A | null | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-11-07 | 124 | A | null | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-11-08 | 124 | A | null | 1 |
| 13 | 2023-11-11 | 124 | A | null | 1 |
| 15 | 2023-11-12 | 124 | P | null | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-11-05 | 125 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2023-11-06 | 125 | P | null | 1 |
| 6 | 2023-11-07 | 125 | P | null | 2 |
| 8 | 2023-11-08 | 125 | P | null | 3 |
| 14 | 2023-11-11 | 125 | P | null | 4 |
| 16 | 2023-11-12 | 125 | P | null | 5 |

And the full query outputs:

| student_id | ts_start | ts_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2023-11-06 | 2023-11-11 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vx9YFsK2).

Comment: Horrible !!!!! mate you are the man. This solution is the best in my case. With just a few modifications I got exactly what I want. I can't thank you enough. You guys are just remarkable.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please give serious consideration to upgrading to a supported MariaDB/MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728413/1741542), and count absent days. Reset the counter on present days or when student changes, e.g.

```
select student_id, timestamp,
       case when status = 'A' and student_id = @student then @absent := @absent + 1
            when status = 'A' and student_id <> @student then @absent := 1
            when status = 'P' then @absent := 0 end as absent,
       case when student_id <> @student then @student := student_id end as tracking_student
from attendance, (select @absent := 0, @student := -1) as init
where status in ('A', 'P')
order by student_id, timestamp
```

See this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oQ7rGkGndKMYcg7kyTgjKv/4)

| student_id | timestamp | absent | tracking_student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2023-11-05 | 0 | 124 |
| 124 | 2023-11-06 | 1 | null |
| 124 | 2023-11-07 | 2 | null |
| 124 | 2023-11-08 | 3 | null |
| 124 | 2023-11-11 | 4 | null |
| 124 | 2023-11-12 | 0 | null |
| 125 | 2023-11-05 | 1 | 125 |
| 125 | 2023-11-06 | 0 | null |
| 125 | 2023-11-07 | 0 | null |
| 125 | 2023-11-08 | 0 | null |
| 125 | 2023-11-11 | 0 | null |
| 125 | 2023-11-12 | 0 | null |